# How to do a GET request with node.js passing a JWT token in header

Tags: node.js, authentication, get, jwt

I have been trying to do a GET request to my server which has is running locally on port 4000.

I generate a JWT token and pass it in the header as follows

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'localhost:4000',
  'headers': {
    'JWT': '<JWT PASTED HERE>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) { 
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

But I keep getting

```
{"errors":[{"title":"invalid_request","id":"Requesting stuff","meta":{"server-time":1591980353},"errorCode":"bad-request","status":400,"detail":"This JWT has invalid path parameter"}],"error_description":"This JWT has invalid path parameter","error":"invalid_request"}
```

My JWT is correctly created, I verified it in https://jwt.io/

Is it because 'request' module is deprecated in node.js?

Is there another way I can achieve the below?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'localhost:4000',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <JWT PASTED HERE>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) { 
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

or

```
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'localhost:4000',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'JWT <JWT PASTED HERE>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
```

Bearer or JWT depends how it is defined in backend

Comment: Tried this, it gives {"errors":[{"title":"unauthorized_client","id":"Requesting stuff","meta":{"server-time":1592090885},"errorCode":"unauthorized-client","status":401,"detail":"No definition of jwt found in header or query string."}],"error_description":"No definition of jwt found in header or query string.","error":"unauthorized_client"}

Comment: Yes so it is accepting Authorization header and is looking for JWT Token that is why it is throwing 401 status code, try Bearer before ```'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Bearer <JWT PASTED HERE>',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }``` if this does not work try directly paste JWT Token in Authorization```'headers': {'Authorization': '<JWT PASTED HERE>',     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }``` It depends on how you access the token from your backend server